# adding images from a folder with php, need correct regex function to use

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm implementing a script that adds images to a page from a folder. The errors i'm getting are as follows:

Warning: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\design.php on line 25

and

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\design.php on line 26

the original script used ereg, which i then replaced with preg_match, but there are still problems, someday i will learn what all of these functions are actually returning.

thanks in advance. i have the feeling there is  duplicate, but i haven't found it yet.

```
$dir = "../mysite/images/";
$dh = opendir($dir);
while($filename = readdir($dh))
{
    $filepath = $dir.$filename;
    //pregmatch used to be ereg. which function is best?
    if (is_file($filepath) and preg_match("\.png$",$filename))
    {
        $gallery[] = $filepath;
    }
}
sort($gallery);
foreach($gallery as $image)
{
    echo "<hr>";
    echo"<img src='$image'><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your preg_match is missing delimiters:

```
preg_match("/\.png$/",$filename))
            ^      ^
```

Also you need to add this before your while loop:

```
$gallery = array();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$dir     = "../mysite/images/";
$gallery = glob($dir."/*.png");
sort($gallery);
```

Comment: Nice one. I've never encountered that function before. Good to learn it exists.

Comment: what does this do differently?